# Why Boltzmann entropy is called equilibrium entropy and not ergodic entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

A system is approach to equilibrium, if its state is independent of initial conditions and the ensemble (probability distribution over the states of the system) is time invariant.

A system is ergodic, if every microstate of the system is equally probable.

The assumption behind Boltzmann entropy is that every microstate should be equally probable. If not, you should use Gibbs entropy.

**Question:**
So, why do we call Boltzmann entropy as equilibrium entropy? I think the equilibrium system needs not to be an ergodic system.
Is there something wrong in my understanding about equilibrium and ergodicity?

Comment: Equal probabilities (i.e. "maximum ignorance" about the microstate of the system) are attained at equilibrium for an isolated system, so it makes sense to call it "equilibrium entropy". This answer may be useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/450987/226902

Comment: Ergodic is a word from mathematics, physicists don't like it. Also, treating every microstate if an isolated system as equally probable is the best option given the macroscopic constraints and lack of further knowledge, regardless of whether the mechanical system is ergodic or not. Thus ergodicity is largely ignored in physics.

Answer (score 1):

> A system is approach to equilibrium, if its state is independent of initial conditions and the ensemble (probability distribution over the states of the system) is time invariant.

Any stationary distribution is time-invariant and independent of the initial condition, yet not all stationary distributions are equilibrium distributions. In an equilibrium state, there is detailed balance, there are no thermodynamic fluxes, nor probability fluxes. A good example is a box of gas between two thermal reservoirs at different temperatures, whereas the distribution of particles and velocities might be stationary, there will be fluxes that avoid equilibrium.

> A system is ergodic, if every microstate of the system is equally probable.

This is not really the definition of ergodicity.

The way I see it is that Boltzmann's formula for entropy describes the entropy of equilibrium systems. In the thermodynamic limit, Boltzmann's (microcanonical) entropy coincides with the entropy computed in other ensembles. Ergodicity is used as a first principle to derive that all states are equiprobable, however, some authors do not make use of the ergodic principle (which is difficult to prove for general systems). Instead, they use the equiprobability among states as a first principle, this can be seen as a prior distribution (if you don't have any information about the system's behavior, you assume equal probability among states).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i didn't really understand what equilibrium is. 
According to Statistical mechanics by Sethna, James P, "A system which is not acted upon by the external world 2 is said to approach equilibrium if and when it settles down 3 at long times to a state which is independent of the initial conditions"
It seems like box of gas in your example is not in equilibrium because there is external heat. However, I think the definition above is quite ambiguous. Can you give me more explanation about this? Is equilibrium imply equal probability among states?

Comment: You wrote "Any stationary distribution is time-invariant and independent of the initial condition" but I think this can only be true if metastable states are excluded.

Comment: @hyportnex I do not agree. In systems with meta-stable states, there is a separation of time scales. First (fast transient): the system evolves to one of the meta-stable states. Second (slow transient): the system oscillates in the vicinity of the meta-stable state.This state depends on the initial condition, and it is characterized by a quasi-stationary distribution. Third (stationary): at temporal scales much larger the system has time to experience rare transitions between meta-stable states. Here the system is characterized by a Boltzmann distribution independent of the initial condition.

Comment: @greatanswer To me, equilibrium means compensation of fluxes, not equiprobability. If there is equiprobability, then the compensation of fluxes is "more trivial": the same number of occurrences of all events in one direction have to happen in the reversed direction with equal probability. Example: if A and B are equiprobable and in equilibrium, then the same number of particles that go from A to B has to go from B to A and with the same (reversed) velocity. If A and B are not equiprobable, then velocities and number of particles differ in A->B and B->A in order to equilibrate fluxes.